# why i got the error using sqlalchemy hive?

Tags: python, hive, sqlalchemy

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


host='user@127.0.0.1'
port=10000
schema ='result'
table='new_table'

engine = create_engine(f'hive://{host}:{port}/{schema}')
conn=engine.connect()
engine.execute('CREATE TABLE ' + table + ' (year int, GDP_rate int, GDP string)')
data = {
'year': [2017, 2018],
'GDP_rate': [31, 30],
'GDP': ['1.73M', '1.83M']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_sql(name=table, con=engine,schema='result',index=False,if_exists='append',chunksize=5000)

conn.close()
```

this is my code make pandas dataframe which save to hive table

but when i run the code i got the error message like this

```
File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 380, in _fetch_more
raise ProgrammingError("No result set")
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyhive.exc.ProgrammingError) No result set
[SQL: INSERT INTO TABLE `result`.`new_table` VALUES (%(year)s, %(GDP_rate)s, %(GDP)s)]
[parameters: ({'year': 2017, 'GDP_rate': 31, 'GDP': '1.73M'}, {'year': 2018, 'GDP_rate': 30, 'GDP': 
'1.83M'})]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

actually i don't know why and the result only one dataframe save at hive table

if someone knows that the reason plz teach me 
thank you

Answer (score 2):

Kindly add method='multi' for batch insert

df.to_sql("table_name", con = engine,index=False,method='multi')

Answer (score 0):

A likely pyhive bug. See https://github.com/dropbox/PyHive/issues/250. The problem happens when inserting multiple rows.